# Extension methods for methods and properties that don't use non-public data

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Generally speaking, I try and write my classes so they are highly cohesive.

Sometimes I have accessors (this problem isn't limited to accessors) which derive their value from non-public data only, which lowers cohesion. (http://www.ndepend.com/metrics.aspx#LCOM)

Take the following class example:

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Death { get; set; }

    public double Age 
    {
        get 
        {
            return (Death ?? DateTime.Now - Birth).TotalDays / 365;
        }
    }
}
```

Ignoring the probable compile errors and lack of error checking, `Age` could easily be an extension method `GetAge` as it doesn't rely on non-public data.

The code would look as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Death { get; set; }
}

public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static double GetAge(this Person person)
    {
        return (person.Death ?? DateTime.Now - person.Birth).TotalDays / 365;
    }
}
```

What is a good approach to determine whether something should be an extension method or implemented in the class itself?

Some arguments against doing this that I find extension methods have lower visibility, you have to know the extension exists, while if it was a class property its existence would be obvious.

For languages that don't use extension methods (C++, php, etc.) the extension method could be written as a static method which accepts a `Person` as it's parameter.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that property/method since it calls `DateTime.Now`. I'd rather pass in a `DateTime`.

Comment: Also, if the class is generated by some tool, it would be convenient to use extension methods.

Comment: A year has 365 days and a quarter I think. I'm not sure this can cause a problem in your code though..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My personal view is create an extension method if:

- The class/interface you wish to extend *is not* created by you.
- The class/interface *is* created by you but the behavior of the extension method is only required in an assembly that doesn't contain the class (e.g. `class Person` is defined in MyApp.dll, but `GetAge()` is only required in MyApp.UI.exe).
- The behavior can be defined against a more generic abstraction than the class itself where the implementation is the same but the classes don't share a common base. e.g. create an `ILifeSpan` interface with `DateTime DateOfBirth` and `DateTime DateOfDeath` properties and create the extension method `public static double GetAge(this ILifeSpan lifeSpan)`

FYI extension methods are just a compiler trick, the generated IL just calls the static method, the `this` keyword just allows you to write less code in visual studio.

when you call `person.GetAge();`, it is compiled to `PersonExtensions.GetAge(person);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a god approach would be to use extension method when you would duplicate data if you would put another property or method into your class.

In your example you would do that: storing (i know you don't store both of them) the date of birth and the age is redundant.